# UITableview filled with images: too much space between images

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I try to make a tableview filled with pictures. Here is what I want and my constraints:

- a 3:2 aspect ratio for the pictures

image in cell.width = image in cell.height with a 3:2 multiplier

- the width of the pictures should take all the screen width

image in cell.centerX = Superview.centerX

image in cell.width = Superview.width

Table View.Center X = Superview.Center X

Table View.width = Superview.width

- space between pictures should be 8

Cell.Bottom = Image In Cell.Bottom + 8

- other constraints :

table view.top = top layout guide.bottom

table view.bottom = red block.top

This is what I get :

[image]

I have three pictures, one visible on screen and the other two visible when scrolling.
I also have a red block at the bottom of the screen. The tableview is behind the red block.

My issue is that there is a white space over each picture. I guess it comes from the content view or cell height that doesn't match my picture height, but I don't manage to make it right.

With a few changes I get a correct space between pictures but the aspect ratio "on screen" is not respected anymore (= the picture width seems to go over the screen width). This is what happens if I add cell.height = Image in Cell.height. And I also get a conflict constraints for aspect = 3:2, height = Image in Cell.height, Image in Cell.width = width, and height = 400.

Do you see what is wrong ?

Thank you,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set your tableView rowHeight statically? I think it should be dynamic, because on the different screens, the cell height will be different according to aspect ratio.

Add this code to your viewDidLoad. This will help make your tableView cell height dynamic:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDymension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60;
```

And to make tableView calculate cell height, add the imageView top constraint to superView(cell) to 0.

Actually, if you want the cell be static height on different screens, just remove your aspectRatio constraint, add imageView heightConstraint equal to cell. And it also will work.

Comment: I don't want a static height, I want a 3:2 aspect ratio. I haven't added anything in my code about rowHeight so I guess this is "static". In storyboard my row height attribute for table view is 400, instead I'd like to respect the aspect ratio and take all screen width, nevermind what the height is. I have added your code in viewDidLoad and add the constraint image In Cell.top = cell.top, space between images is correct but aspect ratio is not respected (the height is very small) and I get conflicting constraints.

Comment: Ok! The problem now in your constraints. What do you mean saying cell.top = cell.top. Actually, you need cell.top = cell.imageView.top. Like your imageView should stick to superView on the top edge

Comment: If it doesn't work. Try to remove all constraints in the cell and add only the AspectRatio of the imageView(3:2) and imageView edges to superView(0 to top,left and right and 8 to bottom)

Comment: Yes I had cell.top = cell.imageView.top, sorry for the typo. I removed my constraints and add what told me to add only. It's simpler and it works now :) Thank you Irzhan !